# Статика pythonanywhere

Tags: python, django, pythonanywhere

Сайт не может найти статику и медиа

[image]

Но этот файл есть в медиа

[image]

мой static [image]

сайт пытается найти стили так:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'static/style_lessons.css' %}">
```

путь в pythonanywhere

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Проблема была в том что у меня автоматически выставилась working directory в папке с моим именем. Нужно было дописать путь по проекта [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Помогло решить проблему. Спасибо.